# "CERT_UNTRUSTED" error on Salesforce API requests

Tags: rest-api

I'm using nForce with NodeJS on Heroku, and today, out of the blue, we've started getting "CERT_ERROR" back from Salesforce on any request made, even though the authentication is being performed correctly.

Has anybody come across this and found out what it actually entails?

Comment: Do you think it may be cause ? [Salesforce disabling SSL 3.0 encryption] https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Salesforce-disabling-SSL-3-0-encryption

Comment: yes. We do see this error especially when the API callout made from Heroku - with the free instances. Some reason the paid heroku dynos do not see this error.

Comment: We're also seeing this error, for requests to staticflickr.com - e.g. GET https://c1.staticflickr.com/2/1324/1009488216_fd12a4e7dc.jpg

Comment: Btw, we're seeing this on free & paid dynos. My guess is that heroku has recently updated something (perhaps slowly rolling out?) that causes a new break in the chain of trust to these apps. Maybe they share a root authority?

Comment: I did wonder if it could be SSL related, but then the same code is working locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with my version of node, related to [issue #8894](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8894). After using NVM to downgrade node from 0.10.34 to 0.10.33, the error disappeared.

Comment: This definitely seems to be the correct answer. It could be my fixed version of request meant a particular version of node was used, though that seems unlikely. Giving you the correct answer since it seems to be a known issue with that node release at least!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an incompatibility or issue caused by the request module. I got  version working locally, and then modified my package.json file to include a specific version of request:

```
"dependencies": {
    "logfmt": "~0.20.0",
    "express": "~3.4.8",
    "pg": "2.x",
    "nforce": "0.10.0",
    "express-jwt": "0.1.1",
    "request": "2.37.0"  <-- previously "2.x"
  },
```

Not ideal, but for now it's working correctly again which is the important thing!

Comment: This didn't work for me. Could you explain why it solved the error for you, or how you realized you needed to update your version of request?